# Laravel pluck and findOrFail not returning correct row

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am using the `Gate` facade to check whether a user can delete a row, or not.

```
 Gate::define('delete-cons', function ($user, $cons) {
        $c_id = Cons::findOrFail($cons)->pluck('c_id');
        return $user->c->id == $c_id;
    });
```

If I output `$cons`, it returns `4`.

```
4   2   1   Mr  Joe Bloggs  male    1234567 0   1_1474822931.png    2017-01-02 17:33:49 2017-01-02 17:33:49 NULL
```

The first column above is the primary key, so as we can see, it should return this row.

However, upon outputting `$c_id` after the query, it shows:

```
#items: array:4 [▼
    0 => 1
    1 => 1
    2 => 1
    3 => 2
  ]
```

I would've expected it to return the last result of `2`, but it returns all 4 rows within the table!

Even if I manually type the ID of the row to get:

```
$c_id = Cons::findOrFail(4)->pluck('c_id');
```

It still returns all rows.

I'm aware I can use

```
$c_id = Cons::where('id', $cons)->pluck('c_id');
```

Which works correctly, but I'm following the Laravel `Gate` example, where FindOrFail throws an exception.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use `pluck()` after `findOrFail()`, because it will just run query to get `c_id` from all rows. Do something like this instead:

```
$c_id = Cons::findOrFail($cons)->c_id;
```

If for some reason you want to use `pluck()`, do this:

```
$c_id = Cons::where('column', $cons)->pluck('c_id');
```

Comment: Works perfectly, and thank you for the explanation! I can accept the answer in 8 minutes.